# Is Facebook Connect (Login) a good solution for an app to use?

Tags: facebook, twitter

I have seen many web apps supporting Facebook Connect...
But when i login through those apps sometimes the authentication is successful but nothing is returned to the app and the login page just goes to a blank page in that new windows and stops... The whole process fails... And this has not occurred once but many times...

So my question is:
Is Facebook Connect a good solution to use in apps or should i use something like Google Login or Twitter Login or OpenID or just a simple password based login or all of the things and let users choose what they want?

And if your answer is app the solutions then wont my database become messy and the app slower because it has look for more data now?

I know it depends on various factors but I just want your opinion, what would u choose and why?

Answer (score 0):

Supporting Facebook connect as login function make sense only if your app has something to deal with Facebook (which is the most of our app today ;-)).

The behave of some app when sucessfully Authenticated and then Authorized is up to these app. 
**FB login give you all the tools to build you own user experience.**
The things become a bit more difficult when you want to introduce FBConnect within already existing login base, while you have to find a way to bind the Identified FB user with your user account.